# pass textbox value as parameter to controller route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, controller

I'm trying to use a textbox value in controller route and am having some trouble with the syntax. Essentially, I have my end users selecting a file and then submitting the data to the api to process and send the data off. I have working static code below, but can't get the xml path to be dynamically populated via the textbox value.

note that (as far as I can tell) the forward slash at the end of the path is required since there is a dot in the file path.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("", "api/food/dummy food file.xml/"))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label class="control-label">Select File</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-default">
                        Browse&hellip; <input type="file" style="display: none;" single>
                    </span>
                </label>
                <input id="food.filepath" name="food.filepath" type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div>
        <button id = "btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>

    }
```

I don't what the syntax would be, but I can't get something like the below to work.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "api/food/" + food.filepath + "/"))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label class="control-label">Select File</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-default">
                        Browse&hellip; <input type="file" style="display: none;" single>
                    </span>
                </label>
                <input id="food.filepath" name="food.filepath" type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div>
        <button id = "btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>

    }
```

Comment: Impossible to understand what your wanting to do here. What is the controller method that your posting this form to. And why do you have a hidden file input without a name attribute that will not bind to a model. And what is the point of posting back the value of a readonly input (you already know its value on the server).

Comment: The controller I am trying to send the file path string to is api/food. As far as why the file path capture is setup like this is because I have jquery tied to the button that lets the user browse for a file and select what file they want to use. The textbox is just used to display that selection. Let me know if there is other info you need for clarity.

Comment: Then show your relevant code, including the POST method and the model. Your code makes no sense so we cannot possible guess what your trying to do.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear for you. The answer below solved the problem if it helps you piece it together better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the form is rendered on server and the value food.filepath is on client, you cannot mix them. Changing form action according to client values need to be done on client with javascript.

You can remove the file from action a add it on submit javascript action, for example by changing `BeginForm` to this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "api/food/", FormMethod.Get, new { onSubmit = "this.dataset.act = this.dataset.act||this.action; this.action = this.dataset.act + this['food.filepath'].value" } ))
```

Comment: this worked like a charm.Much appreciated! for those that also might need this, don't forget to use the proper control name and to change get/post/etc. as is appropriate